# Metal look-and-feel for JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a rather large Java application that uses Swing extensively. The look-and-feel used by the application is Metal and we have a custom theme that lightens some of the colours. I'm building a new component within this application (it's a large project that will deploy in a few years) and would like to use JavaFX for all the GUI parts (several reasons, including being a little more future proof, better APIs, and new widgets I would like to use). However, I don't want to upset the common look-and-feel of the application.

Is there any way (aside from writing lots and lots of my own CSS) to make all the JavaFX components look like the Swing components?

Comment: There are some JavaFX themes over there on the net. Have you looked on them? BTW the Swing's metal LaF is not so great. Changing the theme totally, will give to the users new insights, excitements, inspiration etc.. :)

Comment: I certainly agree with that. Unfortunately, the amount of change to get there isn't feasible right now. The only way I'm allowed to introduce JavaFX is if it looks exactly the same. I tried searching and found several themes, such as AeroFX and AquaFX, but can't for the life of me find anything that looks like Metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a Swing Metal look in JavaFX, start writing lots and lots of your own JavaFX CSS.  I know it's not the answer you want, but it is the answer that is.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much, but hoped it wasn't so. Oh well... at least there's an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could put put the JavaFX components that you need inside the Swing Components. For example, you could put a JavaFX ImageView inside a Swing panel. That way, you get the Swing look (and compatibility) on the outside but the JavaFX functionality on the inside.

I found this tutorial helpful:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

But other than that, I don't think JavaFX has a look and feel identical to metal.